# How do I scale SVG text depending on the size of the container?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I scale svg text in a container so that the inter-letter distance does not change, but the text size changes?
In simple words, so that the font and location of the text remain unchanged. And the size was adjusted to the width of the container.
Thanks!)

```css
.text {
    text-align: center;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10vw;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    svg {
        width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    }
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
        <svg> 
            <text x="0" y="50" textLength="320" class="a">Hello</text> 
            <text x="0" y="100%" font-size="100%" textLength="320" fill = " red " class="b">WORLD</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by changing the SVG to be the entire width of the parent (in this case, the body) and by removing the `textLength` property.  in place, add `text-anchor` for horizontal positioning and `dominant-baseline` for vertical alignment:

```css
.text {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 10vw;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            svg {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-weight: 900;
                color: #fff;
            }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="text">
            <svg> 
                <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" class="a">Hello</text> 
                <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="hanging" font-size="100%" fill = " red " class="b">WORLD</text>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: This snippet does cut off the bottom of the text, but that is because the SVG does not have a defined `height` in CSS.  This is something you will need to add for your final implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
But I need all the text to increase in size of the container, the word Hello is now smaller. I want to get a poster effect

Comment: This is also easy to change.  this demo changes the font size dynamically by using font-size: 10vw; but you can increase the 10vw to however large you need and the scaling will still work. I would suggest you play with different values until you find one you are happy with.